# Python smtplib, timeout on starttls

Tags: python, smtplib

I'm trying to set up some basic email functionality for a small monitoring script I'm running on our office network. Running the script (see below) on my Ubuntu 10.10 server works fine, but when I run it on my Windows desktop machine it times out on `send: 'STARTTLS\r\n'` with `reply: '451 4.7.0 Timeout waiting for client input\r\n'`.

While I will be running this on the Linux server anyway, I'm curious as to why it's not working under Windows. Is it the differing Python versions that are causing the problem?

**Setup:**

SMTP server: Exchange 2010, Windows Server 2008 R2 x64

Python machine #1: Windows 7 SP1 x64, Python 2.7.1 --- (fails)

Python machine #2: Ubuntu server 10.10 x86, Python 2.6.6 --- (works)

**Script:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import smtplib


def main():
    SERVER="exchange-serv"
    FROM = "valid@foo.com"
    TO = ["valid2@foo.com"]
    TEXT = '''\
    From: valid@foo.com
    Subject: testin'

    Test message
    '''

    server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER)
    server.set_debuglevel(1)
    server.starttls()
    server.login('user', 'pass')
    server.sendmail(FROM, TO, TEXT)
    server.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to mind is that the Windows Firewall is blocking outbound socket connections from the Python.exe executable. Have you tried using Python to establish any other types of connections, such as using `urllib2`? If so, what are the results?

Assuming you cannot connect out using Python, then make sure to add Python.exe as an exception into Windows Firewall.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer. Unfortunately it seems this isn't the solution. Another script I'm using for some web scraping is doing fine, so I don't think it's a problem. Either way I added python.exe as a Windows Firewall exception - still the same problem.

Comment: Ok with that out of th eway, since you're using SMTP over TLS (SMTPS), I assume you're connecting to TCP port 465? If you open a command prompt and enter "telnet exchange-serv 465" what happens? We need to confirm whether you can manually connect to the SMTPS port to make sure you have basic connectivity at the OS level.

Comment: Hi, sorry for not having gotten back to you. This issue got heavily down-prioritized and I might not get around to trying to solve it in quite a while. Thank you for your help still. :)